# AWS amazon-s3 rewrite url to query param and go to index.html

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket hosting a static website with a single .html file (index.html) and some .js and .css.

I want to be able to hit mybucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/12345678 and have the url rewritten to mybucket.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/index.html?ID=12345678.

After reading the docs I am not sure I can do this with S3 alone, but maybe I am wrong? What solutions do I have for this?

Note: URL's for the assets (e.g. /css/main.css) need to still work although I could look to inlining everything in the HTML if this is the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly possible with S3. You can use AWS CloudFront and Edge Lambda to do the URL rewrites as required.

- Create a CloudFront distribution and connect your S3 bucket as an origin.
- Create an Edge Lambda inside the distribution and write your URL rewrite rules.

  ```
  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    // this is the request we want to re-map
    var request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    // the request has a 'uri' property which is the value we want to overwrite
    // rewrite the url applying your custom logic
    request.uri = 'some custom logic here to rewrite the url';    

    // quit the lambda and let the request chain continue
    callback( null, request );    
  };
  ```

Comment: Do you assign the `Lambda@Edge` to `Origin Request`?